# "PRETTY good" and "pretty GOOD", which one is better?

Tags: pronunciation

Speaking-wise, the difference between [ PRETTY good ] and [ pretty GOOD ] is the stress.

I wonder would it convey a different feeling when people say [It's PRETTY good] and [It's pretty GOOD]

Comment: I think it's General Reference that (spoken or orthographic) emphasis (indicated by volume/pitch, or distinctive type such as caps/italic/boldface) raises the significance of the target word relative to others nearby. So ***pretty** good* emphasises the ***degree** of "goodness"* (usually, *high*), whereas *pretty **good*** emphasises the ***fact** of "goodness"* (usually, as opposed to *"badness" or neutrality*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stressing GOOD emphasizes that something is good, while stressing PRETTY emphasizes the qualifier that it's only *pretty good*, not *good* or *very good.*

You could almost imagine "PRETTY good" being followed by a "but," for example: "This sandwich is pretty GOOD" vs. "This sandwich is PRETTY good, but I've had better."

Comment: Thank you, it kinda confuse me cause when I look up the meaning of "pretty" on dictionary, they say "(used to give emphasis) to a large degree", so I was thinking if people stress on PRETTY, then shouldn't I have a feeling that the thing is "VERY VERY" good instead of "not very good".

Comment: In general, "pretty" is more conservative than "very," but its meaning can be hard to pin down. A lot of its meaning does depend on the speaker's stress and tone. For example, going from "least good" to "most good," I'd say the order would be like this: PRETTY good, good, pretty GOOD, very good.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, where should I put "not bad" in the scale?

Comment: Depending on the tone used, it would either go before PRETTY good or be equal to it. "PRETTY good" and "not bad" both essentially mean "good, but on the low side of good."

Comment: I think "not bad" can either be as @Nicole says, or it can be much more like "surprisingly good", depending on the tone.  Also, as a Brit, "not bad"/"PRETTY good" can also mean "terrible".